# modify PATH variable outside terminal

Tags: linux, path

I want to add to my PATH variable a folder containing personal scripts (for example ~/myTools). As I've read on forums and tutorials, if I put the corresponding commands (add to PATH and export) to the .bashrc file, the path is correctly modified for anything I launch from a terminal, be it launching a script contained in ~/myTools directly from command line or launching a script that itself does it. But, if I try to launch a script that use something from ~/myTools BY ITSELF, i.e. without calling it from a terminal, then the PATH modification in .bashrc is not made and the script doesn't find things in ~/myTools anymore.

Another example. I write a script "print_path" containing "echo $PATH". If I launch a termi
nal and run "print_path" I see that ~/myTools is contained in my path. If I run "print_path" from the desktop (with Linux Mint 17, double-click, "run in terminal"), then the path printed doesn't contain ~/myTools anymore.

How can I modify my path system wide, and not only in a terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For graphical desktops, you can usually modify environment variables and such in your `~/.profile` file. It is executed for login shells (so when You log in via SSH or on a text terminal), but also when you log in to your desktop environment.

Make sure to use `export` or your changes to `PATH` are only local to the `.profile` file itself, of course.

Note that if you use bash, you should manually source the global `~/.profile` from your `~/.bash_profile` using the `.` command (or delete the latter file outright). Similarly, if you use zsh, you should manually source that file from your `~/.zprofile`, again using the `.` command.